# How do i stop making version while updating some row by calling mongoose save() method

Tags: mongoose

I am using mongoose-version for versioning i need to stop making a version in some cases. How can I stop making a version in save() method. I had try something like that but it is not working

```
collection.save({
      suppressVersionIncrement: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The mongoose version key is used internally by mongoose. You should not mess with it if you are not absolutely sure about what you are doing.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey

You should introduce a custom mechanism for versioning or use a existing module for that:
https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mongoose+versioning